# Pebble game lower bound?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, np, lower-bounds

This paper says pebble games have super linear lower bound for every fixed $k$ https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=62.322433.

Why is it not considered proof of constructive example for a function in $NP$ which requires superlinear runtime?

Comment: The time hierarchy theorem already gives explicit examples of problems in P which require superlinear runtime.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Then what is the problem about looking for problems in $NP$ needing superlinear lower bound? Is it about circuits?

Comment: We're looking for a problem in NP which needs *superpolynomial* time. This is the P vs NP question.

Comment: One approach is via circuits. For general circuits, the best lower bound for explicit functions is linear.

Comment: Yes I know that.  In comm complexity multiparty nof lower bound implies some superlinear circuit lower bound and also I think in pseudoranfom generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time hierarchy theorem gives, for every $k$, a function in P with a runtime lower bound of $\Omega(n^k)$. Unfortunately, this is not enough to separate P from NP: to do this, we need a function in NP with a *superpolynomial* runtime lower bound.

One popular approach for tackling the P vs NP question is via circuits. The best lower bounds for explicit functions are only linear. Perhaps this is the context in which you heard of *superlinear lower bounds* as a seeming barrier.

Comment: precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: @Brout if this is precisely the answer maybe you could consider marking it as one?